# bxslider, can't remove drop dshadow

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, bxslider

Hope someone can help me! I had bxslider working, then all of a sudden today, I reloaded it, and the drop-shadow and border around my slider appeared and I have no idea why it appeared and how to remove. I think I have the right code below to fix it. Please help if anyone can take a quick look for me.

HTML:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
                mode: 'fade',
                auto: 'true',
                randomStart: 'true',
                responsive: 'false',
                controls: false,
                pause: 3500
            });
        });
    </script>

<ul class="bxslider" id="banner_slider">
  <li><%= image_tag "banner.png", alt: "Banner", :class => "banner" %></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0;
    border: 0;
    background: #fff;
}

ul.bxslider{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Again, I had everything working before (without the drop shadows and border), but now all of a sudden it appeared. Hopefully someone can walk me through how this happened, and how to fix. Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: try box shadow none maybe instead of setting it to 0

Comment: hey richlewis - thanks for the reply. tried setting to 'none' and still the same... any other thoughts?

Comment: comment that section of code, `.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport {}`

Comment: hmm - that doesn't change anything either...

Comment: is that css yours or what is provided by bxslider?

Comment: i have the standard bxslider css file in my app, but also have the CSS above in my own CSS file as well (i believe this overwrites the bxsilder CSS settings)

Comment: there lies the problem, you are not overriding anything, your css needs to come after bxslider and be more specific if you want to change anything

Comment: good pt - but if I copy my boxshadow:none CSS code into the bxslider css file, it still doesn't work... i'm slightly confused.

Comment: comment out your bxslider css, then comment out the bxslider code... or better yet comment out your bxslider css and then use the console to inspect the element and turn off the box shadow properties to see which ones are being used...you get me?

Comment: hey rich - thanks so much for all your help. i followed your advice through inspect element, and found the problem to be in a file called bxslider.css - problem is, i have no idea where that file is! the bxslider included file is jquery.bxslider.css, and my own CSS file is welcome.css - really confused where this phantom file is. =/

Comment: ok so is it not in your stylesheets ? well in your welcome.css you could always just be more specific in your css to override

Comment: Amazing - thanks! Found the file in a gem and had to edit the file. yeesh! What a pain, thanks for all your support! appreciate it

Comment: ill write an answer up and you can mark it as accepted? so others can see it and hopefully help them

Comment: absolutely - please do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From our discussion you needed to either locate the bxslider style-sheet (you had it in a gem) or be more specific with with your own CSS

As an example to be more specific you could have done something like this (not exact set up as haven't seen your code)

Original code

```
.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport {
 -moz-box-shadow: 0;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0;
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 0;
 border: 0;
 background: #fff;
}
```

More specific

```
.bx-wrapper.bx-viewport {
-moz-box-shadow: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow:none;
border: 0;
background: #fff;
```

}

or the second solution is to find the original file and comment out the properties that relate to box-shadow